# Load an external properties file in grails

Tags: grails, properties, groovy

I am trying to load the properties file externally, by setting up the system environment.

In my config.groovy file,

```
  println "Config file location --->" + System.getenv("SAM_ENV")
  grails.config.locations = ["file:"+ System.getenv("SAM_ENV")]
```

I have set the system env SAM_ENV value as C:\test\config.properties.

When I try to run the application,I am getting the print value as

```
     Config file location ---> C:\test\config.properties prints properly.
```

The problem is when I try to access the properties file in my controller as

```
        print "PAGINATION1"+grailsApplication.config.PAGINATION1
```

the value of PAGINATION1 is not getting printed properly.

Can any one help me what configuration has to be done to access the external properties file in grails application.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add the below line in config.groovy

grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:grails-app-config.properties"]

environments {
    development {   
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        grails.config.locations = ["file:C:\\conf\\externalfile.groovy"]
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.config.locations = ["file:/opt/config/externalfile.groovy"]
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

If you want to access any property from external configuration(config.groovy) then just declare the property like 

property = property value eg:(ImagePath = "C:\\Users\\Saved Pictures")

access it like grailsApplication.config."property"

eg:(grailsApplication.config.ImagePath)

NOTE: dont use def just a property and its value.
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking for is extending the classpath, which you can achieve by adding a post compilation event in _Events.groovy. Try this:

```
eventCompileEnd = {
ant.copy(todir:classesDirPath) {
     fileset(file:"C:\test\config.properties")
}}
```

You can find more help [here](http://little418.com/2010/04/grails-override-configuration-with-properties-file.html)